# Set color of highchart column according to average or limit value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to set color of highchart column according to average or limit value. I wrote this script; but the problem is that when I move the mouse over the red column it returned to blue !! someone can tell me what to add on my code so that it remains in red ? Thanks

```
<script>
$(function () {
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'donuts1',
            type: 'column',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Les données d\'expression du transcrit : <?php echo $id; ?>'
        },
        subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                        'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["<?php echo join($tableauLogin, '","') ?>"] ,
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '11px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Log2(Expression)'
            },
            minorTickInterval: 1,
            min: <?php echo $min-1;?>,
            max: <?php echo $max+1;?>,
            plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            value: <?php echo $mean ;?> ,// Need to set this probably as a var.
            dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
            label: {
                    text: '<?php echo $leg ;?> : <?php echo round($mean,2) ;?>',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: -100,
                    x: -10,
                    style: {
                        color: '#FF0000'
                    }}
        }]
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 50,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
            },
        series: [{
            name: '<?php echo $name ?>',
            data: [<?php echo join($tableauNote, ',') ?>]
        }]
    },function(chart){

            var max = <?php echo $mean ;?>;

            $.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,data){

                if(data.y > max)
                    data.graphic.attr({
                        fill:'#FE2E2E'
                    });

            });

        });
});
$('#preview').html(chart.getCSV());
</script>
```

Comment: try to change hover color as well

Comment: I finally found the solution by my self
I rempalcer this line:

data.graphic.attr({
                        fill:'#FE2E2E'

by this one

data.graphic.css({
                        color:'#FE2E2E'

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution by my self

I rempalcer this line:

```
data.graphic.attr({ fill:'#FE2E2E'
```

by this one

```
data.graphic.css({ color:'#FE2E2E'
```